# The relationship between interior and exterior Riemann maps

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, analytic-functions, conformal-geometry, analytic-continuation

Let $U\subset\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ be a compact Jordan domain with $\partial U$ connected. Is there a relationship between the exterior Riemann map associated to $U$,
$$\varphi:\mathring{(\mathbb{D}^c)}\rightarrow U^c,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\varphi(z)=az+f_0+f_1z^{-1}+...$$
and the interior Riemann map,
$$\psi:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathring{U},\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\psi(z)=g_0+g_1z+g_2z^2+...\;?$$
Is there, for example, a relationship between the coefficients of the Laurent series of $\varphi$ and $\psi$?

Comment: You should reread the sentence "We know..."

Comment: Good catch, thank you.

Comment: OK, is "we know that" an assumption? It hardly ever holds.

Comment: That's a good point. I will amend my question appropriately.

Comment: OK, now it's a good question.

Comment: this is unclear since Riemann maps are not unique but you need to fix some initial data and then things can change dramatically since the disc automorphism group is quite large; for example, if one takes $U$ the unit disc too and the exterior map the identity, while the interior one some automorphism that sends $0$ to something not zero, it's unclear what one can say beyond trivial stuff

Comment: Right, one needs some normalization for $\psi$ and $\varphi$. In such questions one usually assumes that $int(U)$ contains zero and $g=0, g_1>0$; something similar for $\varphi$ (including $\varphi(\infty)=\infty$). This is spelled out in textbooks on univalent functions.